# pivot on mulitple tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have following three tables

table 1
**mf_tab**

| id | seq | mfr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | goog |
| 1234 | 2 | apple |

table 2
**flg_tab**

| id | seq | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | REL |
| 1234 | 2 | REJ |

table 3
**pn_tab**

| id | seq | pn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | pxyz |
| 1234 | 2 | pabc |

I would like the data in following format

| id | Mfr1 | mfr2 | flag1 | flag2 | pn1 | pn2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | goog | apple | REL | REJ | pxyz | pabc |

Also I would have another case where all there columns are in one table as below. How to obtain smilar result from below table.

| id | seq | Mfr | flag | pn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | goog | REL | pxyz |
| 1234 | 2 | apple | REJ | pabc |

thanks

I can pivot one by one table but could not find a way to pivot multiple tables.
Thanks

Comment: The last table you are showing is the same as the three tables joined. I.e. after joining (which you will have to do anyway) you'll end up with the same table as the one shown last in your request. This means there is nothing different to do, you just save the initial step (joining the tables).

Answer (score 1):

An often used way to pivot is conditional aggregation:

```
select
  id,
  max(case when seq = 1 then t1.mfr end) as mfr1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then t1.mfr end) as mfr2,
  max(case when seq = 1 then t2.flag end) as flag1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then t2.flag end) as flag2,
  max(case when seq = 1 then t3.pn end) as pn1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then t3.pn end) as pn2
from t1
join t2 using (id, seq)
join t3 using (id, seq)
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: well, I could have any number of seq. I mean there could be 10 rows from 1 to 10. I kind of wants to concatenate column ( pn,mfr,flag) with the value in seq column and then show the values

Comment: A SQL query result is a table. And a table has specific columns. You showed a table of id, mfr1, mfr2, flag1, flag2, pn1, pn2. The query that produces this table cannot suddenly produce another table containing mfr3 for instance. What you should do is just select the joined rows and handle the layout in your GUI (app or Website).

Comment: I had incomplete `USING` clauses by the way I've corrected them in my answer.

Comment: There can be upto 20 rows. We have predefined views where there can be upto 20X3 = 60 column. so based on the seq ( 1 to 20)  value we will populate that particular column in the view. I just edited my question to add another scenario for similar result. Thanks

Comment: As SQL queries give you a certain number of columns, you have two options: Write a query to return 60 columns or write a query to get one row per id and seq and handle the display thing in your app. SQL is meant to get the data, how to display it is mainly a task for your GUI layer.

Comment: @Raj Your example has 2 different `seq` values. Then in the comment you say that there may be 10 different values. Later on you say that there may be up to 20 different values. When you finish this process and actually identify that maximum number of rows, you may generate as much `case` expressions as you need. I don't discuss a tool to replicate some text template by number of items